# Spring Integration: Automated integration tests with embedded Broker?

Tags: spring, tdd, spring-integration, activemq-classic, mqtt

Is it in a way possible to, say in memory, start a broker that can be used to execute automated test cases using Spring Integration MQTT? 
I've tried achieving this with ActiveMQ (following https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html) but somehow didn't succeed, maybe anyone has a short working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Spring Integration (Spring Boot) responsibility to provide some embedded broker for such a protocol. If there is one, we could consider to implement an auto-configuration on the matter , similar to what we do for embedded RDBMS, JMS and MongoDB. You really need to consult [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html).

Looks like we can do it like this in the test class:

```
private static BrokerService activeMQBroker;

...

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {
        activeMQBroker = new BrokerService();
        activeMQBroker.addConnector("mqtt://localhost:1883");
        activeMQBroker.setPersistent(false);
        activeMQBroker.setUseJmx(false);
        activeMQBroker.start();
}
```

I didn't try it, but this is exactly what I do to test against STOMP.

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer. I'll try that and come back asap. And yes, the motivation for the question where, exactly like you said, the embedded databases.

Comment: Worked ... check. If anyone else needs it: you need the dependencies to actriveMq-broker, -client, -mqtt. Be careful, that versions match. It took me some time to put everything together properly.